# How to connect to/use MySQL using a remote partition of a SLURM cluster?

Tags: mysql, slurm

I am trying to use Orthomcl, which includes using MySQL in Linux. I have access to a university-wide cluster, which is set up with a basic login interface for very minor commands (<5 minutes, low memory) and multiple remote partitions, which I can only interact with via SLURM. There is no interactive command for these partitions.

I do not have sudo permissions, so I installed a local version of MySQL, and am able to open a MySQL connection via the login and other listening ports (these are all ultimately run via the login).

I was able to get away with this for awhile, and got to the point where I had a large table (~140GB) loaded into my orthomcl database. However, IT finally caught me when I started clustering and the jig is up! But they don't have time to help me find a way to run MySQL on any other partition... I need to run my resource intensive commands on one of the other partitions, but I don't know how to do this without direct command line access or using SLURM syntax.

Any ideas? I am just a poor biologist bumbling around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround if anyone else runs into this in the future. Again, I'm bumbling around so **I guarantee this is not best practice**, but it worked for me.

First, I changed the ports in my .cnf and .config files to a non-login listening port on the cluster.

I used a batch script to start the MySQL instance on a non-login partition from this excellent resource at WSU: https://hpc.wsu.edu/programmers-guide/running-databases/
I couldn't get orthomcl commands to run inside this, so I just cut it after the failsafe stop point.

> sbatch start.sh

I got the name of the partition node it was assigned in the slurm outfile, then I checked that it was open both in the log file and using

> srun --nodelist=nodename mysqladmin -S /path/to/special/socket -P port -u root status

I could then access and use that partition like normal

> screen srun -p batchpartition --time=d-hh:mm:ss --nodelist=nodename orthomclLoadBlast orthomcl.config similarSequences.txt

OrthoMCL specific: Make sure you remember to change your port in the orthomcl.config file!

Hopefully someone will come in with a better answer someday, but this can work in a pinch.